# How to return to outer (local) scope with SSH in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm executing commands remotely through ssh. Is it possible to send output or commands to my own shell? (not to remote)
For example, I wanted to use colored output. I didn't mind having the echo's executed remotely too. But it seems like remote machine does not recognize the syntax and throws errors.

```
ssh myapp "
    mkdir /some/dir || echo "$(tput setaf 1)ERROR$(tput sgr0)"
"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to escape your remote command correctly:

```
ssh myapp "
    mkdir /some/dir || echo '$(tput setaf 1)ERROR$(tput sgr0)'
"
```